# 5k сообщений в секунду через один сокет

Tags: highload, сокет, c++

Доброго времени суток!

Есть некоторое приложение, обрабатывающее данные. К нему приходит клиент/клиенты и начинают активно слать данные. В среднем на одной ноде должно обрабатываться 5-10к сообщений в секунду от одного клиента. Средний размер сообщения 700-1100 байт. 
Сталкивались с проблемами переполнения буферов сокета, увеличили. Все равно скорости не всегда хватает. выше 3к начинает проседать сервер и жрать 100% ( 1 ядра ).

Вопрос: как лучше организовать архитектуру и кто сталкивался с такими вещами? куда посмотреть? почитать?

P.S. естесственно сервер и клиент linux.

Comment: >выше 3к начинает проседать сервер и жрать 100% ( 1 ядра )

А Вы уже распараллелили нагрузку на все ядра? Или у Вас только 1 ядро работает?

Comment: Под сообщением Вы понимаете порцию данных, добавляемых в сокет? Т.е. по сути, просто поток до 10000*1100 байт/с от одного клиента?



А до 3000 пакетов/с загрузка процессора принципиально меньше?

Comment: Да, именно порцию данных в сокет. На 3000 пакетов/с как раз набивается 100%. Вопрос как раз в том, как лучше разгрузить/распараллелить эту задачу. потому что мы не только читаем из этого сокета, мы еще по нему и отвечаем тут же.

Comment: нескромный вопрос - а профайлером, хоть самым простым, смотрели, где тупит? может тупит как раз в самом простом? Мой любимый пример - прибавление по одному элементу к массиву с постоянным перевыделением памяти.

Comment: Смотрели. VTune очень помог. Все же самое трудоемкое из всего это разбор и декодирование/кодирование сообщений.

Comment: @Fe1iX
А асинхронные сокеты(IOCP) не пробовали? Может это решит проблему переполнения?

Comment: т.е. входящий поток всего 437-1375 килобит с одного клиента ? может ваш кодер/декодер неоптимален (как в алгоритме так и в выборе протокола) там же у вас поди асинхронное шифрование ? так может делать как все умные  асинхронно устанавливать хэндшейк а уже синхронно шифровать траффик ?

Comment: @eicto, почему, 3.5-11 МБайт/с.



@Fe1iX, в качестве идеи, если проблема со скоростью шифрования/дешифрования: слышал, что сравнительно новые AVX команды процессора очень ускоряют криптографию. Соответственно, и библиотеки, использующие их должны быть. 


А вообще, наиболее полезно было бы если бы Вы привели в виде отдельных вопросов пару наиболее процессорозатратных мест в вашем коде

Comment: а да, 26-83 Мбит, чет я где-то просчитался, ну все равно не шибко много, а если и много, то для сети а не проца. в любом случае очень и очень редко используется только ассиметричное шифрование, т.к. у него и паразитный траффик больше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если мощности есть - типичное количество одновременно подключённых клиентов существенно меньше, чем количество ядер, то можно сделать, например, так.

Поток, работающий с сокетом, вычитывает данные и кладёт их в очередь задач. Несколько других потоков выбирают из этой очереди, обрабатывают эти данные и кладут результаты в очередь результатов. Первый поток берёт всё из очереди результатов и отправляет клиенту. Всё это реализовывать надо аккуратно, иначе будут проблемы с блокировками, конфликты доступа к памяти... Нотификации о появлении новых данных - семафорами. Если будет тормозить из-за них, можно заморочиться с ручной реализацией через переменные (будет сложно и муторно, но слышал о подобной success story от коллеги).

Или, в качестве фантазии, можно сделать по очереди заданий на каждый поток-обработчик. Каждый поток, работающий с сокетом, знает 4 потока-обработчика (4 проистекает из 10000/3000), и по очереди кладёт им задания.

Но для начала я бы рекомендовал подумать над оптимизацией собственно процесса обработки. Гораздо приятней было бы запихнуть всю обработку данных одного клиента на одно ядро.

Comment: Вот я примерно так же думал. Думаю все же придется вынести в 2 очереди. Тут еще есть такой момент: входящие сообщения раза в 2 больше чем исходящие + требуют декодировки. Все же тоже склоняюсь к 2м очередям и потокам обработки данных уже за ними.